# Steam: Can a game recieved as a gift, be sent back after a short play

Tags: steam, dont-starve-together

I purchased "Don't Starve Together" on Steam (which gives you 2 copies by default), I sent one to a friend as a gift who installed and played it for a short time ( < 2 hours). They decided that they didn't like the game and don't want to play anymore.

Can they now reject the gift, so that I have that copy again to send to somebody else? If so, how can they do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible if your friend asks for a refund, and then you ask for one as well. It's explained in this article on Steam support: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6643-QEUV-0459

> 1. The gift recipient should go to help.steampowered.com and log in
>      with their Steam Account.
> 2. Once logged in, click on "Games, Software, etc.".
> 3. Find and click on the gift in the provided list.
> 4. Click the problem that is occurring with the product.
> 5. Next, click "I'd like to request a refund".
> 6. Finish the request by clicking the box to remove the gift from your
>      account and allow the original purchaser to request a refund.
> 7. If the gift recipient has not initiated the gift refund process, you
>      will see the following when attempting to request a refund.

Once the refund is done, you can request your own refund and then repurchase the game to gift to someone else.

Note: it is possible that this doesn't work with this particular game bundle because you probably played together and thus together have more than 2 hours playtime. Still, I'd recommend putting in the refund request.